# How to update a Listview (imagebutton in listview) from onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-adapter

I am trying to update an image button which is in a listview with an image from a gallery (when clicked). 
Currently I am able to startActivityForResult with an intent to the media store , the gallery opens up and when I choose an image , I get the imagepath in onActivityResult.

My question is how do I update the image on that particular list item (image button) ? I am using a Customadapter extending base adapter and the onClickListener for the image button is in the adapter and the onActivityResult is in the host activity (this method does not know which listitem was clicked).

I am putting in some of my code snippets just to get some perspective.

```
/*
 * Image button click listener for in the Custom adapter
 */
private class ImageOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        imageIntent.setType("image/*");
        ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).startActivityForResult(imageIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE);
    }       
}


 /* onActivityResult  PRESENT IN HOST ACTIVITY*/
 /* On activity result from image button */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("Result Code" + resultCode);
    if(requestCode == FavoriteListAdapter.IMAGE_PICK_CODE && data != null && data.getData() != null && resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri _uri = data.getData();

        //User had pick an image.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Link to the image
        String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
        System.out.println("imagefilepath" + imageFilePath);            
        cursor.close(); 
    }
}
```

Note: I am able to get the image path (so the code is working, I just dont know how to update that particular image button in that list item). Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I wonder if I can package the view in an intent ? does view implement parcelable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the clicked item position as extra in the Intent you start. Then, in onActivityResult you need to get the position from the Intent and use the adapter to get the list item with getItem(position).

Comment: I tried this before and thats the problem , I cant pass in the clicked item position because the onClick method is in an internal class as it is a listener (the index argument in getView needs to be final which does not work)

Comment: Did you tried OnItemClickListener instead of OnClickListener?

Comment: No, I think that would not work for me, as the image button is a view in one single listview item. I ended up passing a setTag on the view and then retrieving it on the click listener with getTag.